# How to find the frobenius number and prove it?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

For this question, I know how to find the frobenius number, but I'm not sure how to prove it. Here is what I have so far. Can anyone please help me out?

Let S = {3,8}. Find the Frobenius number of S,F(S).  Prove that your answer is correct.

frobenius number = g(a,b)

g(3,8) = 3*8-3-8 = 13

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to proving this is the Frobenius number for the set $S = \{3,8\}$.  First, show that you can produce $14, 15, {\dots}$ as a sum of nonnegative integer multiples of the elements of $S$.  Since $\min S = 3$, if you can produce $k$, you can produce $k+3$, so you only need to demonstrate production of $14$, $15$, and $16$, then write how to extend that list by $3$s to get all larger targets.  Then, show, perhaps using the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), that all nonnegative integer multiples of the elements of $S$ do *not* produce $13$.

Comment: How do we do that using induction though?

Comment: @user325 : You've explicitly been told what are your base cases and what property to use in your inductive step.  What more do you need to know?

Comment: When I did the base case, it only works for 14 and 15, but not 16 for some reason. Would it need to work for 16?. Nvm it does work for 16